# Why does phantom.exit() have a 2 second delay?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I noticed that for a simple script like:

```
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";

var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log('Page title is ' + msg);
};

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
  console.log('Status: ' + status);
};

page.open(url, function(status) {
  page.evaluate(function() {
    console.log(document.title);
  });

  phantom.exit();
});
```

calling phantom.exit() will not exit immediately, rather it will wait 2 seconds before doing so. I'm using version 2.1.1.

Do you know where this delay comes from and how I can make phantom exit immediately? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like "open issue":
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14033

I did try your code with the last version and I get the same behaviour.

You can use phantomjs@1.9.X as "jmullo" commented in the issue thread.

Answer (score 0):

Like other browser, phantomjs is just headless. so it's exit() method will do many things, and it may cost couple of seconds.

Comment: When I close desktop Chrome it doesn't take seconds, it's instant. I don't see why it would need to do anything other than call [exit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit). And if this is indeed a complex exit, is there another way to stop phantom immediately?